# How to Test OnOpen() menu populate in Apps Script Sheets Add On?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, add-on, google-apps-marketplace

For months I'm trying, without success, to submit my Google Sheets Add-On to be available at Google Workspace Marketplace. On the last tentatives I'm receiving this message:

> The App doesn’t meet the publishing review criteria on the following:
> Menu - Menu options not shown after App is installed. Please ensure that the add-on correctly uses onInstall() and onOpen() to populate its menu. The menu items populate when the add-on is first installed and when a different file is opened. See Editor add-on authorization.

My question is: **How can I simulate the installation by myself in order to detect what function or variable is causing the problem?**

I already try to avoid declaring Global variables, tried zillions of different ways to populate the menu, but it seems that nothing work. The documentation of Google Apps Script is too generic, the people at GWM doesn't show what error is happening. I really doesn't know what can I do.

How can I avoid a situation that I cannot replicate?
If I just have access to the my own add on GWM page to test it.
Sometimes I ask myself if Google is interested in have third party add on. It's so hard to have information.

Any help will be welcomed.

This is my initialization routine right now:

```
var ui = function(){
  return SpreadsheetApp.getUi()}

/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 * ver: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization
 */

// The onOpen function is executed automatically every time a Spreadsheet is loaded
function onOpen(e) {
  ui().createAddonMenu()
    .addItem('Importar fontes', 'ExtrairComentarios')
    .addSeparator()
    .addItem('Relação de fatores', 'doFactors')
    .addItem('Análise simples', 'doTable')
    .addItem('Georreferenciamento', 'doMap')
    .addSeparator()
    .addItem('Gera matriz multimodal', 'GeraMatrizMM')
    .addItem('Análise multimodal', 'doMultimodal')
    .addItem('Gráfico multimodal', 'doGet')
    .addItem('Gráfico multifatorial', 'doMultifatorial')
    .addSeparator()
    .addItem('Tutorial', 'openTutorial')
    .addSeparator()
    .addItem('Versão atual', 'DoVersaoAtual')
    .addItem('Start!', 'DoStart')
    .addToUi();

    // Script external request
    //eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alasql/0.6.2/alasql.min.js").getContentText())

}

/**
 * The event handler triggered when installing the add-on.
 * @param {Event} e The onInstall event.
 */
function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}
```

P.S. Believed me, I already spend months trying to solve this.

Comment: Start replacing by removing `var ui = function(){
  return SpreadsheetApp.getUi()}` and replacing `ui().createAddonMenu()` by `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()`. Also remove `// Script external request
    //eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alasql/0.6.2/alasql.min.js").getContentText())`

Comment: Thank you @Rúben I already did it in the past. But I dit it again and ressubimitted. If you have more ideas, please share ;)

Comment: You are welcome. I just see that there is an option that calls the doGet function ... that is weird as doGet is a reserved name. What does this function does ?

Comment: I changed the doGet function name. It is a custom function that must have a better name ;)

Comment: Did you get any solution? I am stuck on this stage.

Comment: Hi @UmarTanveer ! I managed to remove ALL global variables. Now it's working. ;)

Comment: Hi @Britto I have also removed all my global variables but still got rejected. Can you please share a sample code of what they accepted? I would appreciate this.

Answer (score 1):

Google [recently released](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases#april_13_2022) a way to test Editor add-ons and updated the docs. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/testing-editor-addons

Now it's possible to create a test deployment for Editor add-ons. Please checkout the details on the previous link.

If you have a Google Workspace account, an alternative might be to publish the add-on for internal use only for testing purposes. Once you have it working you might make a copy to publish publicly, and keep the internal use only for testing future changes.

---

To prevent having problems use the simple onOpen trigger only to show the custom menu. If you want that the add-on does something else on open, do that using an installable trigger, this imply to add a way for the end-user to create this trigger, i.e. include a option on the custom menu for that.

Comment: I already did a test like this and the Add On works like a charm. I'll try to publish for internal use only and see what happens.

Comment: @Britto could you please clarify which aspect of this actually worked for you? I believe I am having a similar issue at the moment and my code.gs `onOpen(e)` logic currently checks the `authMode` and if the `authMode` is enabled & installed not only adds a menu item, but also makes some outbound/external requests. In your experience, was moving the outbound requests to a separate trigger what resolved your issue?